# LibGdX Tiled Map Box2d collision with Polygon Map Object

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Im trying to create a small Side scroller for Android with LibGdx Tiled and Box2D.
I'm using Object Layer to get the collision between Player and the World.
This is working fine if i use Rectangles for the Object Layers.
But when I'm trying to use Polygones the collision isn't working.
What am I doing wrong.
(Sry for spelling mistakes)

Here is my code:

```
for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(5).getObjects()){
            if(object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();

            bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bdef.position.set((rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2) / AoF.PPM, (rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2) / AoF.PPM);

            body = world.createBody(bdef);

            shape.setAsBox(rect.getWidth() / 2 / AoF.PPM, rect.getHeight() / 2 / AoF.PPM);
            fdef.shape = shape;
            body.createFixture(fdef);
        }
        if(object instanceof PolygonMapObject){
           float[] vertices = ((PolygonMapObject) object).getPolygon().getTransformedVertices();
            float[] worldVertices = new float[vertices.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
                worldVertices[i] = vertices[i] / AoF.PPM;
            }

            shape.set(worldVertices);
            bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

            body = world.createBody(bdef);
            fdef.shape = shape;
            body.createFixture(fdef);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I finaly fixed it myself.

```
for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(5).getObjects()){

         Shape shape;
        if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
            shape = getRectangle((RectangleMapObject)object);
        }
        else if (object instanceof PolygonMapObject) {
            shape = getPolygon((PolygonMapObject)object);
        }
        else if (object instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
            shape = getPolyline((PolylineMapObject)object);
        }
        else if (object instanceof CircleMapObject) {
            shape = getCircle((CircleMapObject)object);
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
            bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            body = world.createBody(bdef);
            fdef.shape = shape;
            body.createFixture(fdef);
        }


private static PolygonShape getRectangle(RectangleMapObject rectangleObject) {
        Rectangle rectangle = rectangleObject.getRectangle();
        PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
        Vector2 size = new Vector2((rectangle.x + rectangle.width * 0.5f) / AoF.PPM,
                (rectangle.y + rectangle.height * 0.5f ) / AoF.PPM);
        polygon.setAsBox(rectangle.width * 0.5f /AoF.PPM,
                rectangle.height * 0.5f / AoF.PPM,
                size,
                0.0f);
        return polygon;
    }

    private static CircleShape getCircle(CircleMapObject circleObject) {
        Circle circle = circleObject.getCircle();
        CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
        circleShape.setRadius(circle.radius / AoF.PPM);
        circleShape.setPosition(new Vector2(circle.x / AoF.PPM, circle.y / AoF.PPM));
        return circleShape;
    }

    private static PolygonShape getPolygon(PolygonMapObject polygonObject) {
        PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
        float[] vertices = polygonObject.getPolygon().getTransformedVertices();

        float[] worldVertices = new float[vertices.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(vertices[i]);
            worldVertices[i] = vertices[i] / AoF.PPM;
        }

        polygon.set(worldVertices);
        return polygon;
    }

    private static ChainShape getPolyline(PolylineMapObject polylineObject) {
        float[] vertices = polylineObject.getPolyline().getTransformedVertices();
        Vector2[] worldVertices = new Vector2[vertices.length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length / 2; ++i) {
            worldVertices[i] = new Vector2();
            worldVertices[i].x = vertices[i * 2] / AoF.PPM;
            worldVertices[i].y = vertices[i * 2 + 1] / AoF.PPM;
        }

        ChainShape chain = new ChainShape();
        chain.createChain(worldVertices);
        return chain;
    }
```